# RSA Public key transfer from C# to Android

Tags: java, c#, android, xml, cryptography

I have a simple C# webservice that generates a 2048 RSA public encryption Modulus and Exponent.
I want to transfer it manually (copy and paste) to my Android app (using an XML File).
How can I make it so that it uses the same encoding.

I'm struggeling with this problem for over a week. I think I'm going nuts.

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: On C#-side you get the publicKey with the xml-export option to a file. On Java-side you read the xml-file, read the modulus and exponent and convert both values via Base64-decoding to byte arrays, convert them to BigInteger and with both values you can rebuild the publicKey for usage.

Comment: Could you give me a code example pretty please?

Comment: It'd be amazing. I'm really breaking my head witht this issue :/

Comment: Kindly note that asking for code is off-topic on SO.

Comment: RSA is not a block cipher, hence generating an IV does not make any sense here.

Comment: that's right Robert. I've just corected it